# A prime in parentheses

Tags: math-mode, brackets, superscripts

I would like the prime in  `$\mathfrak E ^{(')}$` to look like the normal prime in `$\mathfrak E'$`.

[image]

Also I might like smaller parentheses around the prime.

Answer (score 9):

Here, `'` is interpreted as `<next-smaller-script-mode>\prime`.  Thus, since you are already in superscript mode with the `^{(...)}`, you just want to use `\prime`, instead of `'`, or else the `\prime` appears in the next smaller script mode, which is `\scriptscriptstyle`.

To get smaller parens is a lot of typing, because you want the parens in `\scriptscriptstyle`, but the `\prime` in `\scriptstyle`.  I show this as the last case of the three shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
 $\mathfrak E ^{(\prime)}$ 

 $\mathfrak E'$

 $\mathfrak E ^{\scriptscriptstyle(\scriptstyle\prime\scriptscriptstyle)}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The apostrophe can be used to get a `\prime` symbol, but you need to remember that the apostrophe *already* contains its `^` instruction.

So `'` is good *only* if it appears next to the symbol we want to add the prime to (or next to another `'`, because sequences of `'` characters are transformed into the appropriate sequence of prime symbols). So, in general, `'` inside a brace group is wrong.

I often see something like `f^{'}`, which is wrong in view of the description above.

You can define a command that makes inputting the “parenthesized prime” easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallerparen}[1]{\mathpalette\smallerparen@{#1}}
\newcommand{\smallerparen@}[2]{\raisebox{0.6\depth}{\scalebox{0.7}{$\m@th#1#2$}}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\pprime}{O{1}}
 {
  ^{\smallerparen(\prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \prime }\smallerparen)}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\mathfrak{E}\pprime \quad \mathfrak{E}\pprime[2]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]